# LESS CSS how to modify parent property in mixin

Tags: less, less-mixins

I'm looking for a less syntax to do something like that:

```
.button-default{
  background-color: rgb(100,200,250);
  :hover{
    .button-hover-effect-mixin();
  }
}
.button-warning{
  background-color: rgb(250,100,0);
  :hover{
    .button-hover-effect-mixin();
  }
}

.button-hover-effect-mixin(){
    background-color: darken(PARENT.background-color, 50%);
}
```

I know how to do that with a parameter or a global variable but the hover-effect schould not always be designed to change the background-color.

Comment: You cannot target a parent element with LESS because you cannot target a parent element with CSS (LESS preprocesses to CSS and has no knowledge of the html context the CSS is in).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean the `.button-default` and  `.button-warning` are those "PARENT"s for the `.button-hover-effect-mixin` then your friends are [variables](http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature):

```
.button-default {
    @background-color: rgb(100, 200, 250);
    background-color: @background-color;
    &:hover {
        .button-hover-effect-mixin();
    }
}

.button-warning {
    @background-color: rgb(250, 100, 0);
    background-color: @background-color;
    &:hover {
        .button-hover-effect-mixin();
    }
}

.button-hover-effect-mixin() {
    background-color: darken(@background-color, 50%);
}
```

You also can make this variable to be a parameter of `.button-hover-effect-mixin`. Additionally don't miss `&` near `:hover` selector (without `&` it expands to `.button-default :hover` and this probably is not what you need, see [Nesting](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-nested-rules)).

---

And... if this goes in right direction and those colors are the only difference between the buttons I would rewrite the whole snippet to something like this:

```
.button(default, rgb(100, 200, 250));
.button(warning, rgb(250, 100, 0));

.button(@name, @color) {
    .button-@{name} {
        background-color: @color;
        &:hover {
            background-color: darken(@color, 50%);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks max! I did not knew, the LESS compiler can access this @background-color variable in the mixin from snippet one. The Solution for me would be declaring a few more properties as variables to make them accessible in the mixin. Snippet two is what i ment with "not only the background-color" but thanks anyway - also to ScottS.

Comment: I just looked at the code and thought, pff, what a dumb second example is :)