# How to override a LESS mixin variable based on a parent's variable

Tags: css, variables, less, overriding, parent

I am a newbie, so be gentle.  I am sure my terminology is incorrect too:

suppose I have my own jumbotron override:

```
.jumbotron {
  background-color: #ff4400;
}
```

and then I want to have a custom override of that where I inherit the above class and only override its background color using its color as a parameter to "lighten()".  I can't figure out the syntax:

```
.Myjumbotron {
    .jumbotron;
    /* not sure what goes below for "parent.background-color" */
    background-color: lighten(parent.background-color, 30%);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LESS allows you to define variables. So you can define a variable for the parent's color and then use it within the `lighten` function like below:

```
@parentColor: #ff4400;

.jumbotron {
  background-color: @parentColor; /* Using the parent color variable */
}

.Myjumbotron {
    .jumbotron;
    background-color: lighten(@parentColor, 30%); /* Lightening the parent color */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/DikEj)

**Note:** This would produce two `background-color` setting but that should be fine because CSS takes the last available setting as the value and in this case it would be the lightened value.

**Option 1 without using variables:** For achieving the `lighten` or `darken` effect without using a parent color variable, refer to the work-around answer posted by [ScottS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/369707/scotts) in [**this thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591445/lighten-parents-unknown-background-color-in-child) or the demo that [seven-phases-max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2712740/seven-phases-max) has posted in the comments.

**Option 2:** (contributed by seven-phases-max in this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24878924/how-to-override-a-less-mixin-variable-based-on-a-parents-variable/24880702#comment38826257_24880702))

Best alternative solution (if you cannot modify the original `.jumbotron` code to use variables and have the `.myJumbotron` element as not a child of the parent `.jumbotron` element) would be the below:

```
.jumbotron {
    background-color: #ff4400;
    color: white;
    padding: 2em;
}

.Myjumbotron:extend(.jumbotron) {
   @back: fade(white, 60%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(@back, @back);
}
```

[**Demo for Option 2**](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/gsvHD)

Comment: Harry, sorry for the delayed response.  Well, this sort of works in this case but that is not the real root of my question.  I want to know if it's possible, from a syntax point, to reference the mix-in/parent's variable.  What you have done is not the same.  For example, suppose I have a parent variable and I don't know HOW is was set - I just want to reference it and then modify it.  With your solution, I have to know that @parentColor was what the parent used.  In most cases I will not easily be able to know how or what variable used - I just want o take it and modify it.

Comment: It is not possible to perform functions like lighten/darken etc on the parent's color without using a variable. Refer to [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21591445/lighten-parents-unknown-background-color-in-child) for a work-around using opacity. That is the only possible option to achieve the effect.

Comment: Harry, I looked at the thread you reference and it says "if you want to do this, use LESS".  Yet, no such solution is provided.  Again, I am no closer to my simple question: in LESS, "can a child class reference a parent variable, and if so, what is the syntax?"

Comment: @staggart: I guess you missed seven-phases-max's comment in that thread. Check [**this pen**](http://codepen.io/hari_shanx/pen/DikEj). It essentially creates a lightened/darkened version of your parent color by adding white/black to the parent's color. This method doesn't require you to know the colors. In a direct way **you cannot reference** the parent's color without using variables.

Comment: yes, I did miss that example with the fades.  Interesting.  I happened to pick and example of "change" to a setting the could be accomplished in a round-about manner (i.e., no direct reference to the parent variable because the fade is "layered" on top of what's beneath).  But, again, I ask, is it possible to reference a parent variable - according to the ScottS post (that I quoted in my previous comment, he says "yes, to do this, use LESS", but then gives no direct example (the fade is not a direct example since no parent variable is accessed for the effect). [see next comment]

Comment: [continued from above] Other references say it's not possible to "see/reference" a parent value.  I'm inclined to believe it's not possible, even with LESS or no one knows how to do it.  I get 100% that it's not doable in CSS.  From a language processing standpoint, since the LESS compilers know "all values" at all times, it is certainly possible - from a syntax standpoint they either did not want to do it or never thought of it or ???

Comment: I give you an answer award because of the effort but I would prefer the definitive "yes" (and an example) or "no" (and here's where it says so.)

Comment: @staggart: In that answer he doesn't say that we have to use LESS to achieve this effect. He merely points out that darken/lighten on child can be achieved in a different way. If you refer to seven-phases-max's comment in the question (or) to Damien Black's answer you will find all of them saying the same which in essence is, there is no direct way of doing this. You either have to use variables (or) the work-around provided in it. You can also have a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762336/less-css-how-to-modify-parent-property-in-mixin) for a similar item.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/810) is an issue thread from the Less.js GitHub for a similar looking item. Given that the same (or a similar) workaround is provided there we can safely assume that no other option is available. Luke Page (the one who answered that GitHub issue) and seven-phases-max are part of the [Less Core Team](http://lesscss.org/about/) so I trust them to know more about LESS than us :)

Comment: Just in case, If (like in the example snippet) the "child" jumbotron invokes "parent" one as a mixin it is possible to use slightly more "clean" code w/o polluting global scope by specific variables: [demo](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/DnwJa). This won't work though if instead of copying "parent" rules you'll inherit them with `extend` (which would be more optimal in this case).

Comment: And another alternative solution (best if you cannot modify the original `.jumbotron` code), how to "overlay" things w/o putting "child" jumbotron HTML into "parent" jumbotron HTML: [demo](http://codepen.io/seven-phases-max/pen/gsvHD).

Comment: @seven-phases-max: That overlay sample is a very good one. Do you mind me adding that sample to the answer? Future readers may very rarely go through all comments (especially when they find a checked mark on the answer).