# How to use "currentColor" CSS 3 keyword in LESS?

Tags: css, less

There is this new keyword in CSS 3 called `currentColor` which, as the name easily suggests, refers to the element's current color value.

Now I would like to use this keyword in LESS' `darken(@color,@percentage)`-function. The following throws an error in LESS compiling:

```
h1 {
    color: red;
    background-color: darken(currentColor, 75%);
}
```

The errormessage:

```
undefined_methodError: error evaluating function `darken`: 
Object [object Object] has no method 'toHSL'
```

Please ignore the fact that this is not yet supported in all browsers. Anyone know how to make this work in LESS?

Comment: Not an exact answer to your question but if my interpretation of what you are trying to do is correct then [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24878924/how-to-override-a-less-mixin-variable-based-on-a-parents-variable/24880702#24880702) may help you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is fundamentally impossible to do that.

LESS compiles to regular CSS.
Any behavior that cannot be expressed in CSS also cannot be expressed in LESS.

In particular, the LESS `darken()` function works by changing the color at compile-time.
Since `currentColor` isn't known until runtime, you can't do that.

Comment: So this was a dumb question, I guess. Thanks for letting me know!