# Operations on base values with Less CSS

Tags: css, less, operations

Hi I'm new to using Less and trying to make the best of the features it offers. What I would like to do is the following:

say I have a few anchor elements in html

```
<a href="#" class="blue-link">Blue link</a>
<a href="#" class="red-link">Red link</a>
<a href="#" class="green-link">Green link</a>
```

and I have the following css

```
.gen-link-prop {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 10px 40px;
    color: #fff;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 5px;
}
@blue-link-color: #9999ff;
@red-link-color: #ff9999;
@green-link-color: #99ff99;

.blue-link {
    .gen-link-prop;
    background-color: @blue-link-color;
}

.red-link {
    .gen-link-prop;
    background-color: @red-link-color;
}

.green-link {
    .gen-link-prop;
    background-color: @green-link-color;
}

.blue-link:hover, .red-link:hover, .green-link:hover {
    background-color: darken(@<-- reference to base color here--<, 20%);       
}
```

I want to be able to apply an operation to a property value that is already applied to the element. Is this even possible? Or is it something simple that I missed somewhere. Help is greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't think you can write a common `a:hover` selector and darken whatever was the base color for that `a` (not even with Less). However I remember seeing a different approach which involves something like placing a darker (blackish) overlay on top of the element while it is being hovered on.

Comment: I updated the code so I'm using the hover for each specific class. In a simpler situation this should work (like just adding a general color to all the hovers). The thing I want to do is apply the function the actual value.

Comment: I meant that you can't group them into one single rule (either with one selector or a group of selectors).

Comment: hmm ok that's what I was thinking that maybe this isn't possible. I was wondering if maybe there was a way to reference the base value of the property and modify that.

Comment: Maybe this article would help you http://meri-stuff.blogspot.no/2012/06/inheritance-and-variables-in-css-with.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24878924 and other Q&As linked there.

Comment: @seven-phases-max: Can't believe I forgot one of my own threads (*embarrased*).